# z-index - I can't click a region

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

i'm trying to fix a bootsrap card that is unclickable, cant also type input into form inside of it.
The issue is that I use z-index to place the card "behind" header and footer, into the second floor.
It works well but actually, it disable input type or click for the card.
How can I fix it? trying to specify different z-index for the classes inside card I'm still unable to fix it..
[EXAMPLE HERE](https://unknow.tv/prova6.php)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue is that I use z-index to place the card "behind" header and footer

Actually, you use `.card{ z-index: -1}` which places the card behind the `<body>`,
and `<nav>` header and `<footer>` are still with `<body>`

It is proper behaviour, it works as you ordered :). Do you really need `header` and `footer` on a different layer? Above `<body>`?
Then you should set `nav, footer{ z-index: 1}` and remove <s>`.card{ z-index: -1}`</s>

Check your page with [Validator](https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/?ucn_lang=en), please

Comment: Thanks mate to make me understand.. it do the trick!